# Making draggable POI-map using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I try to make such kind of map:
http://www.plotbrowser.com/search.cgi
but first, I can´t see, where they saved the coordinates and the text.
If you look to the sources, there are no coordinates or other data.
I expected that.
But they must be anywhere downloaded, because I can click (already visible/downloaded)
popUps and get new content even when the internet-connecition is blocked
(for sure, offline I can´t drag the map ...).

Is a good lesson to start
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable
or something else?

I'm working with wampp.

Answer (score 3):

Source of the Leaflet Map is found in [leafletembed.js](http://www.plotbrowser.com/leaflet/leafletembed.js). It's using AJAX calls and [LatLongBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) to get the JSON. I would suggest taking time to look over the [Leaflet Docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need an ajax call to fetch the coordinates and data from your database and place marker on to the map.